# Removing the first 8-10 letters from a post?

Tags: php

I have a widget that shows all the post names. All the post names are "Chapter ## - Title"

I would like the php in the widget to remove the "Chapter 1 -" or "Chapter 12 -" for example so that just the part after the Chapter is left....

Comment: Did you know you can [accept the best answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for each of your questions? This will give a reputation increase to you and to the answerer. Now it looks like you never "return the favor" by not accepting any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a new query loop that I use that shows the latest ten post titles/permalinks in the category mycategoryname and strips the first 15 characters from all of the titles.

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=mycategoryname&showposts=10'); ?>
<?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Permanent Link to: <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
<?php $mytitle = get_the_title(); $mytitle = substr($mytitle,15); echo $mytitle; ?></a>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

If you need to select which posts to strip either 8 or 10 characters, you'd have to select them by some sort of criterea and alternate that character number.

Answer (score 1):

You can use php strpos function with substr function go get just the part you want for example:

```
$title = substr($post->post_title,strpos($post->post_title, " - ");
```

this will look for " - " inside the string and return all chars after it.

### Update

simply change your code to this:

```
<li>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php printf(__('Permanent Link to %s','PureType'), get_the_title()) ?>">
        <?php substr($post->post_title,strpos($post->post_title, " - "); ?>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: I like that simple approach - how would I insert it in this code:

Comment: [code] <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php printf(__('Permanent Link to %s','PureType'), get_the_title()) ?>">
            <?php truncate_title(40) ?>
            </a></li>[code]

Comment: @dreamgrowers: i updated the answer.

Comment: I really appreciate it. I get a syntax error using that exact code and would still like to include the truncate. Thoughts?

Comment: Create a pastebin or pastor of you full code so could see and help you better